# Eclipse run as junit test missing

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit4

I am trying to run a test case but when I right click on the test class, there is no option for run as junit. I know there are similar questions, I tried them but did not work for me. The only thing is that in one question they suggested to take a look at 
Window > preferences > java and see if there is any junit. For me there is not but I do not know how to resolve it.I have installed it. I added it to the plugins and also in my build path but still it does not show up.

Comment: Did you install junit?

Comment: yes I have installed it. I added it to the plugins and also in my build path.

Comment: but still it does not show up.